# bash: Extract with regex only the domain names from a text file

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to extract with regex only the domain names from a text file.

OS: Ubuntu

```
grep -oP '(?<=display_url":")[^"]+' /tmm/script/string.txt

test7.com\/WRlklv5ir4Y
test8.com\/r\/IBlkO\/com6ents\u2026
```

My command (which does not return any result)

```
grep -oP '(?<=display_url":")[^"]+' /tm/script/string.txt | grep '(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]'
```

The desired output:

```
test7.com
test8.com
```

Comment: Could you please post sample of input too without command to be more clear in question, please edit your post in code tags.

Comment: Aside from the trivial solution `grep -o '^[^\][^\]*' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use the fact that domain name is the first thing on the line and separated by something like

```
cut -d/ -f1
```

Your data seem a little more messy than a plain url, so maybe `tr -d '\\'` or something alike will be needed.